# Can't finish MR when using Sqoop transfer data from HDFS to MYSQL

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop

While transferring data from HDFS to MySQL, a MapReduce job gets spawned. But, it gets stuck and does not get completed.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://crxy2:3306/test --username root --password 19911130 --table info --export-dir sqoop_export
```

I see following in the logs:

```
Warning: /software/sqoop-1.4.6.alpha/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /software/sqoop-1.4.6.alpha/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /software/sqoop-1.4.6.alpha/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /software/sqoop-1.4.6.alpha/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
15/12/02 01:17:37 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
15/12/02 01:17:37 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/12/02 01:17:37 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
15/12/02 01:17:37 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/12/02 01:17:38 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `info` AS t LIMIT 1
15/12/02 01:17:38 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `info` AS t LIMIT 1
15/12/02 01:17:38 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /software/hadoop-2.6.0
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/344126e97612def1e3976c1978c2e75e/info.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
15/12/02 01:17:42 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/344126e97612def1e3976c1978c2e75e/info.jar
15/12/02 01:17:42 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of info
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/software/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/software/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/12/02 01:17:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
15/12/02 01:17:45 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
15/12/02 01:17:45 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
15/12/02 01:17:45 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/12/02 01:17:46 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/12/02 01:17:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/12/02 01:17:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/12/02 01:17:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
15/12/02 01:17:50 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
15/12/02 01:17:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1449047829255_0001
15/12/02 01:17:51 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1449047829255_0001
15/12/02 01:17:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://crxy2:8088/proxy/application_1449047829255_0001/
15/12/02 01:17:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1449047829255_0001
15/12/02 01:18:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1449047829255_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/12/02 01:18:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:19:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:19:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:29:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1449047829255_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1449047829255_0001_m_000001_0 Timed out after 600 secs
15/12/02 01:29:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:29:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:40:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1449047829255_0001_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1449047829255_0001_m_000001_1 Timed out after 600 secs
15/12/02 01:40:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:40:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:50:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1449047829255_0001_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1449047829255_0001_m_000001_2 Timed out after 600 secs
15/12/02 01:50:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/12/02 01:51:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/12/02 02:01:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1449047829255_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1449047829255_0001_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0


15/12/02 02:01:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 32
File System Counters
FILE: Number of bytes read=0
FILE: Number of bytes written=370395
FILE: Number of read operations=0
FILE: Number of large read operations=0
FILE: Number of write operations=0
HDFS: Number of bytes read=556
HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
HDFS: Number of read operations=15
HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
HDFS: Number of write operations=0
Job Counters 
Failed map tasks=4
Launched map tasks=7
Other local map tasks=3
Data-local map tasks=4
Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=2732612
Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=2732612
Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=2732612
Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=2798194688
Map-Reduce Framework
Map input records=0
Map output records=0
Input split bytes=504
Spilled Records=0
Failed Shuffles=0
Merged Map outputs=0
GC time elapsed (ms)=759
CPU time spent (ms)=5170
Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=245080064
Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2529026048
Total committed heap usage (bytes)=46792704
File Input Format Counters 
Bytes Read=0
File Output Format Counters 
Bytes Written=0
15/12/02 02:01:13 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 556 bytes in 2,607.4894 seconds (0.2132 bytes/sec)
15/12/02 02:01:13 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
15/12/02 02:01:13 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!

2015-12-02 08:01:15,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Application Finished - Succeeded  TARGET=RMAppManager RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1449047829255_0002
2015-12-02 08:01:15,793 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application Attempt appattempt_1449047829255_0002_000001 is done. finalState=FINISHED
2015-12-02 08:01:15,793 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1449047829255_0002 requests cleared
2015-12-02 08:01:15,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1449047829255_0002 user: root queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
2015-12-02 08:01:15,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1449047829255_0002 user: root leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0
2015-12-02 08:01:15,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1449047829255_0002,name=info.jar,user=root,queue=default,state=FINISHED,trackingUrl=http://crxy2:8088/proxy/application_1449047829255_0002/jobhistory/job/job_1449047829255_0002,appMasterHost=crxy2,startTime=1449069503787,finishTime=1449072069229,finalStatus=FAILED
2015-12-02 08:01:15,796 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher: Cleaning master appattempt_1449047829255_0002_000001
2015-12-02 08:01:15,873 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Null container completed...
2015-12-02 08:01:15,873 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Null container completed...
2015-12-02 08:01:16,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Null container completed...
```

Comment: You need to check map reduce logs, to get the root cause of the issue. Can you check the logs and paste what the error it is throwing as part of reduce phase?

Comment: I added the logs above please help me take a look.

Comment: Information is not good enough, you need to go to reducer task and provide the errors generated in reducer task. Above details are from the job log, you need to drill down to task logs.

Comment: I extracted all the log of this mr.   how can i drill down to the reducer task from all of the log? is there any keyword like 'reduce' to search?

Comment: Link will look like this: http://quickstart.cloudera:19888/jobhistory/logs/quickstart.cloudera:8041/container_1449114544347_0001_01_000003/attempt_1449114544347_0001_r_000000_0/cloudera

Comment: ok,i see.I figured out the problem.it was caused by my data’s pattern. i change it i can run forwards now.thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you figured out after checking the reducer's logs?

Comment: yes,I have learnt that. thanks alot for your guide!

Answer (score 0):

Questioner was looking at incorrect logs. He is able to troubleshoot the issue by going through failed task logs as per the suggestion in the comments section.